# Tint an image downloaded from network dark in Android

Tags: android, image, picasso

I have to download an image, tint the image so that it becomes dark and then set it as a background to a `LinearLayout`. I have tried the following code:

```
Picasso.get().load(url).into(new Target() {
  @Override
  public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {
    BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bitmap);
    bitmapDrawable.setColorFilter(new PorterDuffColorFilter(Color.BLACK, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN));
    linearLayout.setBackground(bitmapDrawable);
  }

  @Override
  public void onBitmapFailed(Exception e, Drawable errorDrawable) {

  }

  @Override
  public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable placeHolderDrawable) {

  }
});
```

The problem is that the image is not being seen and the background has become completely black. How do I show the darkened image?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `PorterDuff.Mode.OVERLAY`:

```
bitmapDrawable.setColorFilter(new PorterDuffColorFilter(Color.BLACK, PorterDuff.Mode.OVERLAY));
```

You can read how it works exactly [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/PorterDuff.Mode#overlay).
Hope this helps!

Comment: I tried this: `BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bitmap); Drawable bitmapCompat = DrawableCompat.wrap(bitmapDrawable); DrawableCompat.setTint(bitmapCompat.mutate(), Color.BLACK); nextItemLayout.setBackground(bitmapCompat);`. It didn't have any effect.

Comment: I am sorry I had misread your question. I have adapted my answer now it should work :) At least it did for me when I tested it. Just let me know if you get your desired result!

Comment: Now the image is coming but no dark tint.